# What is the unique piece of information for a client browser?

Tags: browser

I am working in PHP. I need a computer dependent login system. I mean to say that a user cannot login using multiple computer it will be restricted to only one machine. If so, I will need administrator to handle this case. I tried to make this IP dependent, but I saw that in a network I can login with all computers as they are sharing the same internet connection.

Comment: There is no guaranteed way to do this. There are hundreds of strategies out there to attempt what you are after but each of them can be overcome. The MAC address put forward by Adel Boutros below is usable if close enough works but can be spoofed fairly easily.  EDIT:  Just thought about this further... the MAC address you get in web requests, much like the IP address is the Address for the External Router for the network so MAC address will not work either.

Comment: hmmm. makes sense. What Bueller said is true

Comment: How about Session Variables then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the MAC Address which is unique for every machine and is given by the Constructor of the machine.

**PS:**

> @Emmanuel: You can have the same computer name on two machines.

**UPDATE:**

Some links form getting MAC address in PHP:
http://nazmulb.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/getting-mac-address-using-php/
http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1179119.htm

Comment: The MAC address can be spoofed easily.

Comment: @Bueller it remains better than the machine name